# Difference between GICD_ISENABLER and GICD_ICENABLER for disabling the interrupt

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm

As per GIC manual, 
GICD_ISENABLER

```
Reads 
0 Forwarding of the corresponding interrupt is disabled. 
1 Forwarding of the corresponding interrupt is enabled.
Writes 
0 Has no effect.
1 Enables the forwarding of the corresponding interrupt.
```

GICD_ICENABLER

```
Reads 
0 Forwarding of the corresponding interrupt is disabled.
1 Forwarding of the corresponding interrupt is enabled.
Writes 
0 Has No Effect
1 Disables the forwarding of the corresponding interrupt
```

Is there a need for 2 registers?  Can the purpose be solved by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a background, you can read chapter section 2.5 of [ARM Appnote 179](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/AppsNote179.pdf) on the **Cortex-M's bit-banding** feature.  The issue is to avoid [read-modify-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93modify%E2%80%93write) cycles.  Suppose you have some *main line* code which wishes to disable interrupt **#X**.  During this process, an unrelated interrupt **#Y** occurs and disables that interrupt.  The CPU process maybe as the following sequence,

1. Mainline reads *interrupt mask*, with **#X, #Y** clear.
2. Interrupt occurs
3. Interrupt disables int **#Y**
4. Mainline resumes, setting int **#X** mask
5. Mainline write *interrupt mask* without **#Y** set.

While the reading from these registers is equivalent, the writing is very important and race conditions as outlined above and very common with interrupts.  You may *disallow* masking of interrupt in an *irq service routine*.  However, there is often **hardware**, that just won't shut-up and it is often needed to do this kind of masking.

You can certainly mask **all** interrupts in the main-line when masking an interrupt bit.  However, this increases *interrupt latency* and is generally bad for the system.  With the *dual register* structure, it is possible to avoid the *read-modify-write* and mask the interrupt bits atomically.

Comment: This is a very common feature in *hardware register sets*.  I don't know a generic name; perhaps *write one to clear* (abbrev **w1c**) is the most common.  An important feature of the `GICD_ISENABLER` is that writing a *zero bit* will not disable that interrupt, preventing the inverse condition outlined above (a race while enabling)... This is less common in practice.